# Renaming Shape Group- small issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have grouped shapes in worksheet with the following codes

```
Activesheet.drawing objects.Group
```

Now I want to rename the group name but I am not finding code.

I tried the following:

```
Set shpGroup = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
shpGroup.ParentGroup.Name = "MyGroup"
```

also tried following

```
Activesheet.group.select
selection.name = "MyGroup"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the GroupObjects collection.  The following code will name the last group of shapes that you've grouped...

```
With ActiveSheet
    .GroupObjects(.GroupObjects.Count).Name = "MyGroup"
End With
```